# Can anyone tell How to write the Real and Imaginary parts of Circular polarisation in terms of Unit vector components?

Tags: optics, polarization, complex-numbers

In my computational simulations, i want to mention the 'real' and 'imaginary' parts of 'Circular' and 'Elliptical' polarised light as an input. Now the syntax of that input is such that i have to give the input as (Re_x,Re_y,Re_z), where the 'Re_' represents 'real component' of the polarised light. (say circular polarised).
The syntax is similar for imaginary part, say 'Im_x, Im_y, Im_z'.

So, now i want understand how split this 'circular' and 'elliptical' lights in terms of such component unit vectors? assuming the the light or electric field is written in terms of complex numbers.

Say, incident field is in the form **bar (A_0)**=|**A_0**|.(**e_x**, **e_y**, **e_z**)
where **e_x, e_y** and **e_z** are complex numbers. ** *bar** implies a Vector.

Comment: Does this article help? - [Complex number representation of polarisation states](https://www.fiberoptics4sale.com/blogs/wave-optics/101446598-complex-number-representation-of-polarization-states)

Comment: For future questions on this site, please use MathJaX to format mathematical notation.  [Here's a tutorial on how to do so.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Farcher Thank you. Incidentally, i was and I am reading the same, and to some extent its clear. But i need a bit of more input for my understanding.

Comment: @Farcher i could not edit previous comment fully. So writing here. I need to confirm my my understanding. Say, for Circular polarisation if i mention the vector components as for real '0' and for imaginary as '1', and the amplitude would be a chosen value. Right? Similarly, for elliptical also same components i.e. real=0' and imaginary=1 and the amplitudes are to be assigned differently. As per the reference link you cited then Ay ≠ Ax. Is my above understanding correct? (assuming i am talking about left-handed polarisation)